# How to avoid jcenter error or replace it when jcenter shutdown today

Tags: android, maven, bintray, jcenter, maven-central

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.applovin:applovin-sdk:+.
     Required by:
         project :app > prox-lib:prox-utils-max-saleoff:2.3.5
      > Failed to list versions for com.applovin:applovin-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/applovin/applovin-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/applovin/applovin-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

It seem like jcenter stop working today. Last Friday, my project still work fine, until today.

I run **./gradlew build --warning-mode all** and got this error.

Does anyone know when jcenter will work again or how to avoid jcenter error ?

(I tried with mavenCentral() and still not working)

Answer (score 0):

as a temperary measure, you can use mirror site

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Jcenter mirror
        maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }
        // other repo
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working for me.. I'm still getting this error "Failed to resolve: com.dmcBig:mediapicker:+"